# $f(x)=\prod_{j=1}^n(x-x_j)=0$ when $x=x_j$. But, how can a variable be equal to an object tied to the index?

Tags: functions, products

I found the function

> $$f_i{(x)}=\frac{\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^n(x-x_j)}{\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^n(x_i-x_j)}$$

on "Answer Book for Calculus" by Micheal Spivak -- question 3, 6(a). Which stated that this polinomial equaled $1$ at $x_i$ (which of course, is clear to me) and that $f_i(x)=0$ at $x=x_j$. My problem is with the last statement. Since $j$ is part of the index, how could there be a  number $x$ equal to $x_j$ which isn´t a number per say?

Comment: Why isn't $x_j$ a number? Another way to write this is: $$f_i(x_j)=\begin{cases}1&i=j\\0&i\neq j\end{cases}$$

Comment: Also, "index" is fine for products as well as sums.

Comment: $\sum_{j=1}^n (x_j)=x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_n$. At no point do we add $x_j$ since $j$ is just the index of summation and not a number. This is what I mean by "not a number". Am I right on $j$ not being a number? Maybe thats what I´m not getting.

Comment: Oh, I see. In the expression $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$ the $j$ is bound. So $j$ is not "bound" outside that sum. You could use $k$ outside, so that $f_i(x_k)=\dots$ depending on whether $i=k.$ But you can re-use $j$ without much risk, as long as you take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I got your question right, but maybe my explanation helps anyway.

You have a given pool of numbers, which we call $x_1...x_n$. For any $i \in \{1...n\}$ you define a function $f_i$ with the property that $f_i(x_i) = 1$ and $f_i(x_j) = 0$ for $j \neq i$. When defining $f_i$ the variable $j$ is not in use, so we can use it as an index. Though, when evaluating $f_i(x_j)$, the variable $j$ is  in use, so you should use another index like $k$, when plugging $x_j$ in the defining term...

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I see my problem was with the reusing of $j$ to denote the index.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad I could help :)